# Uso de "Ellos" como pronombre singular en tercera persona

Tags: gramática, pronombres, persona-gramatical, comparación-de-idiomas

He leído un articulo ([They as gender-neutral third-person singular personal pronoun](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2016/01/08/donald-trump-may-win-this-years-word-of-the-year/)) que habla sobre el uso de *They* como gender-neutral third-person singular personal pronoun en la lengua inglesa.

Y me di cuenta de que en español se usa de la misma manera.

Por ejemplo, imagina que alguien te llama a tu casa, tú no estás y algún familiar toma el recado. Cuando llegas a casa quien tomó el recado te dice:

> Familiar- Te **llamaron** hace un momento.
>
> Tu- ¿Quién llamó?
>
> Familiar- No sé.
>
> Tu- ¿Qué **dijeron**?
>
> Familiar- **Dijeron** que luego te llaman.

En el ejemplo estamos usando un "ellos" como singular para referirnos a una persona que no conocemos.

Es decir que usamos **ellos** en lugar de **él** o **ella**.

> Familiar- **Ellos te llamaron** hace un momento.
>
> Tu- ¿Quién llamó?
>
> Familiar- No sé.
>
> Tu- ¿Qué **dijeron Ellos**?
>
> Familiar- **Ellos dijeron** que luego te llaman.

La pregunta es: ¿creen que sea algún rasgo heredado del latín? El latín influyó bastante en el inglés, y tal vez podría haberlo heredado (hipotéticamente) tal como los tiempos compuestos.

¿Sabe alguien si ocurre algo similar en otros idiomas romances?

Comment: Me parece una pregunta muy interesante. Sucede incluso si estás viendo a la tercera persona: puedes decir _han venido a buscarte_ incluso si ves que sólo ha venido uno.

Comment: Como antecedente, en latín existe el género neutro (no sólo un pronombre, como en inglés, que además está reservado a seres inanimados). Creo que eso lo hace menos probable, pero no podría descartarlo. Quizá puedes preguntar en [latin.SE]

Comment: La respuesta puede estar en el epígrafe 33.4s de la Nueva gramática española. Ahora mismo desde el móvil no puedo consultarlo bien, pero aparece como ejemplo la misma frase "te han llamado por teléfono".

Comment: En este caso, yo normalmente refiero a este uso de la 3.a persona plural como un pasivo indefinido, porque a pesar de no ser pasivo (tanto como el pasivo reflejo técnicamente está en la voz activa), actúa casi como si lo fuese, simplemente omite el agente.  Sé que los otros idiomas ibéricos lo emplea: me llamaron hace poco = ligaram-me há pouco = ligáronme hai pouco = llamáronme va poco. Tal vez el francés, con su sujeto explícito obligatorio, será diferente. @Rafael también tiene el neutro el castellano, pero solo existe en el singular.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo parece que [33.4.s](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/z.cgi?t=85306700851858607708206180&s=2&ap=33.4s) lo describe. No encuentro el artículo entero y he tenido que ir cacho a cacho.

Comment: @fedorqui ya he podido leerlo, [el epígrafe](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SMIikFzLtEVBcDfz) registra el uso, pero no su origen, que es lo que pregunta el usuario.

Comment: En catalán tb  pasa: "T'**han** tructa fa una estona", "Qui ha trucat?","Que **han** dit?"

Comment: En psicología cognitiva existe el concepto de _singular they_. No recuerdo ahora si está directamente relacionado con esta pregunta, pero apostaría que es un rasgo psicológico universal, que no nace de diferencias idiomáticas.

Comment: En realidad, aquí no tenemos sujeto singular ni plural; es una construcción impersonal. Creo que no tiene nada que ver con el uso en inglés. También tenemos la segunda persona impersonal (*tienes que estudiar mucho para sacarte una carrera en cuatro años*), que no hace referencia a nada que vaya a hacer necesariamente nuestro interlocutor. Estas frases no tienen sujeto y, en el caso que nos ocupa, es incorrecto usar el pronombre *ellos*.

Comment: Creo que es incorrecto decir *«Ellos te llamaron»* o construcciones similares usando un sujeto explícito *«Ellos»*. En este tipo de construcciones el verbo va en tercera persona plural, pero el sujeto siempre es tácito: *«Te llamaron»*. Esto lo convierte en una especie de sujeto impersonal. El énfasis recae en la acción.

Answer (score 3):

Sin duda es una construcción interesante. Yo creo que el *quid* de la cuestión está en el hecho de que estas frases implican que no se conoce el número de personas que ejecutan la acción. En el caso de frases como:

> Mañana vendrán a reparar la caldera

es posible que vengan una o varias personas. Se usa la tercera persona del plural cuando no se conoce el número de personas que ejecutarán la acción. Incluso en el caso de frases como:

> Te han llamado por teléfono, era tu hermana

dado que la primera parte de la frase sigue el patrón de frases en las que no se conoce el número de personas que ejecutan la acción (aunque en este caso lo que se desconozca sea a la persona que la ha ejecutado), y luego la segunda parte de la frase lo aclara. Este caso del español se puede consultar el en [epígrafe 33.4s](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=purFmLzqJgsRcDUo) de la Nueva Gramática Española.

Sin embargo, ¿de dónde viene la construcción? Pues es bastante antigua. Casos de frases en los que se desconoce el número de personas que ejecutarán o han ejecutado la acción los hay desde hace siglos:

> *Que aun hasta en lo que es música y en los cantares hallamos esto mismo, pues las seguidillas arrinconaron a la zarabanda y **otros vendrán** que las destruyan y caigan.*
>
> - Mateo Alemán, "Primera parte de Guzmán de Alfarache", España (1599)

Y si seguimos hacia atrás:

> *Bien me as aconsejado, et dizes verdat; enpero veré a qué tornará la mi çima de mi fazienda et **qué mandarán** de mí fazer.*
>
> - Anónimo, "Calila e Dimna", España (1251)

Me cuesta trabajo encontrar ejemplos anteriores en el CORDE, pero si en el siglo XIII ya existía esta forma, es muy posible que proceda al menos del latín vulgar. No tengo apenas conocimientos de latín, así que no sabría buscar ejemplos en esa lengua.

Sobre lo de su uso en otros idiomas, en italiano se da. En el siguiente ejemplo se usa "me han llamado" incluso a pesar de que quien lo dice sabía que era una persona concreta quien llamaba.

> *"Ah, sei qui [...] finalmente ti trovo. Come ti senti?". "Un po' stanca ma non c'è male. Figurati, **mi hanno telefonato**". "Ti hanno telefonato? -ripete incredula- e chi?". "Una mia amica di Milano [...]".*
>
> - Mirella Ducceschi, "L'incidente", Italia (1990)